# C# como enviar um email contendo um hiperlink usando System.Net.Mail?

Tags: c#, html, email

Criei uma classe para o envia de emails usando a biblioteca System.Net.Mail.

Para realizar o envio formato a mensagem em HTML. A mensagem que estou enviando é a seguinte:

```
<div style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 600px; font-family:Calibri,sans-serif;">
    <p>Olá Aluno,</p>
    <p>Recebemos uma solicitação para redefinir sua senha de acesso ao sistema MEUSISTEMA.</p>
    <p style="color:#1762aa; font-size:18px"><a href="www.MEUSISTEMA.com/ResetPassword?RecoverCode=893P7IN83FXO5UO2WASHTQI65LCP792O">Clique aqui para redefinir sua senha. </a></p><br>
    <p><strong style="font-size:18px">Importante: </strong>O link para redefinição de senha tem validade de 1 hora. Após este período será necessário gerar um novo link.</p>
</div>
```

O envio está sendo feito corretamente, no entanto quando abro o email para verificar a mensagem que foi enviada, o hiperlink está estranho:

> Olá Aluno,
>
> Recebemos uma solicitação para redefinir sua senha de acesso ao sistema MEUSISTEMA.
>
> [www.MEUSISTEMA.com/ResetPassword?RecoverCode=V3A8AZ379JZIWSTPXZK6HT90Y8BIZYYZ]Clique aqui para redefinir sua senha.
>
> Importante: O link para redefinição de senha tem validade de 1 hora. Após esse período será necessário gerar um novo link.

Qual seria a forma de corrigir isso?

Comment: Qual é client de e-mail? Isso parece ser uma regra de renderização em quem está recebendo e não uma consequência do seu envio.

Comment: Imaginei que pudesse ser o cliente, testei o envio para o Hotmail e para p GMail. O problema persistiu. Conforme a resposta do @perozzo o problema era o formato do hiperlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque o link da seguinte forma:

```
<a href=\"http://www.MEUSISTEMA.com/ResetPassword?RecoverCode=893P7IN83FXO5UO2WASHTQI65LCP792O\">Clique aqui para redefinir sua senha.</a>
```

Perceba a contra barra adicionada `\` no início e fim do link e o `http://` no início.

E garanta que seu objeto `MailMessage` tenha a seguinte propriedade definida para `true`:

```
IsBodyHTML = true;
```

Exemplo:

```
MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
email.IsBodyHTML = true;
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. A propriedade 'email.IsBodyHTML' já estava setada como true. O problema era de fato a falta do 'http://'

Comment: Para que servem as barras invertidas?

Comment: As barras invertidas seriam no caso de você tentar colocar uma " dentro de uma string que já foi aberta com ", aí o compilador entenderia que você estaria fechando a string, mas no seu caso estaria apenas abrindo a tag href com ". A barra invertida serve para dizer que a " faz parte da string e que você não quer finalizar a string.