# Link do arquivo em um diretório no e-mail

Tags: c#, email, link, ssis

Boa tarde.

Estou tentando disparar um e-mail pelo SSIS usando o código C# cujo corpo do e-mail possui um "clique aqui" para abrir um arquivo que está em um diretório. 
Já tentei o esquema em HTML usando o "Clique aqui e o esquema de VBA. 
Até já fiz como o tópico 
[C# como enviar um email contendo um hiperlink usando System.Net.Mail?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/288371/c-como-enviar-um-email-contendo-um-hiperlink-usando-system-net-mail) 
alguém poderia me ajudar, por gentileza? o código é:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
```

```
    public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("xxx.xxxx@xxxxx.com.br", "xxx.xxxx@xxxxx.com.br", "Assunto", "Bom dia a todos."+"\r\n" + "\r\n" + "Arquivo atualizado. Para conferir,  <a href= \\xxxxx\\xxxxxxx\\xxxx\\bbbbb\\eeeeeeee\\arquivo.xlsx"><"Clique aqui"></a>");
     msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("exchange.empresaX.com.br", 587);

        client.EnableSsl = true;

        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx.xxxx@xxxxx.com.br","SENHA");

        client.Send(msg);


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o protocolo `file` para abrir um arquivo local num caminho **absoluto**:

```
string link = @"file:\\C:\caminho\para\o\arquivo.txt";

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(
    "xxx.xxxx@xxxxx.com.br",
    "xxx.xxxx@xxxxx.com.br",
    "Assunto",
    "Bom dia a todos." + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + $"Arquivo atualizado. Para conferir, <a href=\"{link}\">Clique aqui</a>");
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

O mesmo não suporta endereços relativos, como `.\arquivo.txt`, por exemplo. Você deverá especificar o caminho completo do arquivo, o nome do arquivo e sua extensão.

Lembrando que, o arquivo deve existir na máquina destino.

Se o arquivo estiver online, utilize o `https`. Se for num servidor FTP, `ftp`.

Leia mais sobre o protocolo [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

Comment: Boa tarde CypherPotato, 
O código compilou, porém no corpo do e-mail, só está aparecendo "Arquivo atualizado. Para conferir," e não aparece o Clique aqui =(

Comment: @fercs89 é porque o `clique aqui` estava como `<"clique aqui">` e isso é erro de sintaxe em html. Corrigi a resposta.

Comment: Funcionou!!! Muito obrigada @CypherPotato !